# SVN - Backing up Subversion?

Tags: svn

I had a website developed by an offshore development team. I am not a technical person myself so I have a bit of fear that the developers may not have given me the full code. Perhaps it is still depending on their servers for some of the pieces. Two questions:

1. Is there a way to rest assured that I have everything to run the website independently of them?
2. I have several files called entries that have a dir followed by two urls pointing to their own servers that begin with svn.theirdomainname.com/. Should this be a cause for concern or is this something that was only used when in development mode and which is on my own server now?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my questions.

Answer (score 0):

1: Firstly if you have a copy of the source code that you didn't [checkout yourself form their SVN server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) but was provided to you by the dev team you can't be sure it's all there. If the development hasn't fully finished yet you can't actually be sure it is all in the repository as well. It is another issue how you've gotten into this situation from a business perspective.

1. I don't really understand the question, but yes these files could be something left over from development which does not mean that they are somehow harmful but it does also not mean they're not! We can't actually know that from the information you've provided.

If you still have access to your repository you can do a checkout of the [HEAD revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) by doing the following:

```
svn co URL trunk/ --usernameYOURUSERNAM --passwordYOURPASSWORD
```

**URL** is the url :D, such as http://svn.theirdomainname.com/, if they are using the HTTP protocol, or svn://svn.theirdomainname.com/ if they're using SVN. There are other access methods as well. Actually the better option for you is to do an [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) as it will export a clean directory tree where [svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) will also get the SVN metadata.

By checking out the HEAD revision you can at least be sure that you have the latest (clean**?) version in the repository.

Finally you other option is to get the code from the production server if any. If the full functionality, by specification, is working there then the code must also be fully there.

** You can consider it "clean" but it could also have problems in it - this knowledge is possessed by the development team.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you could be sure that you have everything in hand to run your server even without your dev team is to **fetch the live version** of your website from your server.

It's not guaranteed that the guys did actually use the version in `trunk` to put on the server. They could have used any other branch too or even add something to the live version that isn't contained in any branch at all.

If you want to backup the whole SVN repo including all branches and tags, you could use [`git svn`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-svn). This will convert the complete history of the SVN repo (all commits, all branches, all tags) into a Git repository that you could hold locally.

But again: what you need is not the development history but the version actually running on your website. Get that version and watch it carefully.

Comment: What do you mean by watch it carefully? Please elaborate.

Comment: I mean: print the code, put it in a safe, burn three DVDs with the code, give one to your mum in England, one to your cousing in Australia and one to a penpal in Finland. Just ensure that you don't lose it in case that the servers disks crash and your developers have retired on the Kayman Islands.